# Genymotion Android 4.4.2 Api 19 doesn't boot anymore

Tags: android, boot, knapsack-problem

I'm using `Genymotion` with 4.4.2 API19 custom phone 7. `Genymotion` is not able to boot. So I boot from the virtual box. After a untracked pid series on the virtual box, it starts the android logo, the disk light show some activity, but nothing happen. I've tried everything from you suggestions. What could I do now? Any idea is well accepted! Thanks in advance! best regards Paul.

Comment: @madhan kumar [Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/13863578) Don't use inline code to highlight random terms

Comment: @Sanoop ok I'll not use here after.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, but wouldn't even see the Android logo. It turned out to be caused by connecting to the VPN at my workplace.

The reason for that is because the DHCP server range used by my VirtualBox host-only adapter was in conflict with that on the network at work.

Preferences -> Network -> Host-only Networks -> Double-click -> change the IP address and DHCP server to different values. Then **reboot your host machine** to ensure the setting change it applied (VirtualBox won't apply the changes until all VMs using the network are closed, and some processes seem to hang around for some time).

Answer (score -1):

Open your virtual box and power off your virtual device , and then open genymotion and delete your device and add it again , if you add your previous device exactly , there will not need to any download